# Slide Toggle won't work properly (icons are not properly changing)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#toggle > li > div").click(function(){
if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('#toggle ul').slideUp();  
    $("span.minus-btn").removeClass('minus-btn'); // When slide goes up remove 'minus-btn' class
}
$(this).next().slideToggle();
});


$("#toggle > li > div").click(function() {

     $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass('active');

if($(this).hasClass("active")){
   $("span.plus-btn", this).toggleClass('minus-btn');
     }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4Q9V/14/)

Comment: I think you can remove your last $("span.plus-btn", this).toggleClass('plus-btn'); in the else.

Answer (score 0):

You change the plus/minus icons only on the clicked element. You could change all span elements to "plus-btn" and than the active one to minus. Like you first remove all active classes `$("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");`

Update:

```
$("#toggle > li > div").click(function() {
      $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass('active');      

     if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $("span.plus-btn", this).toggleClass('minus-btn');
     } else {
         $('.minus-btn').removeClass('minus-btn');
     }
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4Q9V/7/)</kbd>

Comment: to give me a clear understanding about this. can you go ahead and edit the js fiddle demo?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove 'minusbtn' class when it slides up.

replace this with your code :

```
 $("#toggle > li > div").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#toggle ul').slideUp();
        $("#toggle *").removeClass('minus-btn');
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


$("#toggle > li > div").click(function() {
      $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass('active');

     if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $("span.plus-btn", this).toggleClass('minus-btn');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#toggle > li > div").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#toggle ul').slideUp();
         $("span.minus-btn").removeClass('minus-btn');
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


$("#toggle > li > div").click(function() {
        $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');

if($(this).hasClass("active")){
       $(this).find("span.plus-btn").toggleClass('minus-btn');
 }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jobinjose01/rmGnv/2/)